# create new column based on most frequent value of previous columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, frequency, operation

I have a number of columns in a data frame that represent replicates of an experimental result.

Example here

```
        1a      2a      3a      4a      5a
1      154     152     154     156      NA
2      154     154     154      NA      NA
3      154     154     154     154      NA
4      154     154     154     154      NA
5      154      NA     154     154      NA
6       NA      NA      NA     154      NA
7      154     154      NA     154      NA
8      154     154      NA     154      NA
9      154      NA     154     150      NA
10     149     149      NA     149     149
```

What I would like is to create another column which has the value that occurs(>=2)from each of the other columns.

```
        1a      2a      3a      4a      5a    score 
1      154     152     154     156      NA    154
2      154     154     154      NA      NA    154
3      154     154     154     154      NA    154
4      154     154     154     154      NA    154
5      154      NA     154     154      NA    154
6       NA      NA      NA     154      NA     NA
7      154     154      NA     154      NA    154
8      154     154      NA     154      NA    154
9      154      NA     154     150      NA    154
10     149     149      NA     149     149    149
```

EDIT: Modified example above to demonstrate.
flodel's answer of using the mode was initially successful however it would use a value even if it only occurred once. I would like it to either come up NA or a character string (which ever is easier)if there are not 2>x values in each row.

Comment: that median thing won't work. Plus what happens when nothing occurs >=2 times or two scores occur two times in the same row?

Comment: Totally - it was my quick fix attempt I shall rectify that above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for the median but the mode, which is easy enough to define yourself:

```
Mode <- function(x, min.freq = 1L) {
  f <- table(x)
  k <- f[f >= min.freq]
  if (length(k) > 0L) as.numeric(names(f)[which.max(f)]) else NA
}

test$score <- apply(test2, 1, Mode, min.freq = 2L)
```

Comment: This seemed to work initially until I noticed that in cases where there were less then two identical results (my example above didn't include any)or if there were equal amounts of different values it would output either of those. I shall clarify my question further

Comment: Perfect - works on both less then two values and on matched amounts thanks a lot!